# How to pass parameter on char variable and print it

Tags: c, parameters, buffer, printf

I have a variable

```
char buffer[250] = "Your score is %d";
```

and i want to print it like

```
printf("%s", buffer);
```

but also pass a second parameter so i can display it like `"Your score is 50"`

Is it possible that way?

Comment: There is only one format string, and that's the first parameter. The parameters after it never get used as format strings which means you can't use `%d` inside any of the other parameters except the first string.

Comment: Downvotes are part of SO, they're a quality control mechanism, stop taking it personally. stop talking about it and if they help that's good if they don't then that's just a random fact of life.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can print the string itself, like so:

```
printf( buffer , 50) ;
```

Comment: thats very unsecure in it's nature because you could manipulate program memory with user input in buffer

Comment: @nio What user input?

Comment: it depends what can land in buffer as a format string, if it was just a numeric format string nothing will happen, but if you had a string in buffer, a wrong input like `"%s%s%s%s"` can crash your line of code if there's not enough supplied format arguments. For the security problem google up https://www.google.com/#q=format+string+vulnerability

Comment: Trivial. You still assume there is some kind of input in buffer.

Comment: Humans barely have the attention span necessary to understand & learn one thing at a time. But whenever there's a (perfectly legit) security issue there's tens of people adding security related cruft to a valid question & answer duo.